# Associating View and ViewModel pairs in XAML without repetitive code

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate, dry

I have read [a very nice tutorial](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) about letting ViewModels do their stuff while the views just switch themselves via databinding with `DataTemplates`.

I succesfully made a window which has an ApplicationViewModel, which in turn has a hardcoded DummyViewModel as its CurrentScreen property

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Aplication"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Killer Application" Height="900" Width="1440"
        WindowState="Maximized">

    <!-- This view has its viewmodel as data context, which has a CurrentScreen property -->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:AplicationViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- each ViewModel will explicitly map to its current View - while this should happen EXPLICITLY, no? -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DummyViewModel}">
            <v:DummyView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- Doc, are you telling me I'll have to fill this up for EVERY VIEW/VIEWMODEL? -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:YetAnotherViewModel}">
            <v:YetAnotherView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <!-- the content is bound to CurrentScreen property of the data context -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentScreen}" />
</Window>
```

I would like to have some (very simple and direct, if possible) way to get the same result WITHOUT having to exhaustively code one `DataTemplate` Window Resource for every possible screen the window can show. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If you're doing MVVM, then you should be using an MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx). For example, [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) will do view location and automatic binding based on conventions.

Comment: Installed it with Nuget. Have already heard about it, but I was hesitating in adding a Framework dependency in my project. I guess I'm gonna have to live with this idea, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by using the `DataTemplateManager` found in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way).

It enables to declare the View-to-ViewModel relation like this:

```
manager.RegisterDataTemplate<ViewModelA, ViewA>();
manager.RegisterDataTemplate<ViewModelB, ViewB>();
```

This is still explicit, but it reduces a LOT of overhead of having to do it in XAML. Think about namespaces for instance.